# Ubuntu - WordPress Installation Error - New Version 2020 - Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I'm new in UBUNTU. I've installed:

**1. php:** (PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS ))

**2. MySql:** mysql  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

**3. Server:** Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

WordPress Requirements was

---

**Requirements**
We recommend servers running version 7.4 or greater of PHP and MySQL version 5.6 OR MariaDB version 10.1 or greater.
We also recommend either Apache or Nginx as the most robust options for running WordPress, but neither is required.

All requirements are above from requirements.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02O3e.png)

Then start apache2 service and when hit the wp installation menu on brown getting this error:
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8PPK.png)

**What is the problem for WrodPress.**

Comment: You need to install the extension as is stated. This can be done with:`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`. For future questions, please do not upload images of your errors, but copy the actual message.

Comment: I've tried this Command, Not working :(

Comment: Can you share more details? Which problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**
After remove and reinstall PHP, Apache2 and Mysql.

Thanks All.